# MYSQL to Elasticsearch on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I have MySQL tables within a rails project.I want to join them and insert the values into a single elastic search index .

I made models for each MySQL table and a model for that combined index in the elastic search.

For the elastic search model I use

```
include Elasticsearch::Model
include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
```

How could I keep the elastic search index updated with all values in the MySQL database?

Could that be done with a background job ?

Comment: If you include the `Callbacks` module the elasticsearch-model gem will automatically update the index with changes you make to the models and you don't need a background job. 

What do you mean with a combined index? I think you should have an index for each model, which you have setup correctly like this.

Comment: I mean by the combined index an index which has the result of joining all the MYSQL tables.
ex : If table x has x_id , x_info and table y has y_id,y_info,x_referencing_id
and they are joined .
I want an elastic search index  to have x_id,x_info,y_id,y_info

please note that I made the 3 models x,y and the last one for the elasticsearch index

Comment: Could you show me the model code for the combined model? Do you duplicate all information in those models?

Comment: Yes, I duplicated them in the migration and in the model I put the 2 includes mentioned in the question .